# How can I make it beep after compilation ends?

Tags: xcode

The subject says it all...

I simply want Xcode to make a beep or any other noise once the compilation process is over.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Project menu select "New Build Phase" and then select "New Run Script Build Phase".

You can then add shell commands to that script, i.e.

```
/usr/bin/say "Build completed"
```

Comment: Cool! Even with speech output! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 14):

In Xcode 4, you can simply open the "Behaviors" tab in Preferences, select the Build Succeeds event and check the "Play sound" or "Speak announcement" option. Same goes for failed builds and other important events:

[image: Xcode Behaviors]

Answer (score 9):

Better yet, read http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/chapter_2_section_7.html

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXBuildSuccessSound /path/to/sound.aiff
```